# Want to show Directory Tree of server (PHP) at client side using FLEX?

Tags: php, apache-flex, tree, iterator, directory

Using RecursiveDirectoryIterator of PHP i am able to create directory tree and can even flatten it using RecursiveIteratorIterator class , but I want to create directory tree structure which TREE component of flex understands . The following is an array structure in php which flex understands.

```
array('label'=>'rootDirectory','children'=>array(array('label'=>'subFolder1','children'=>array(array('label'=>'file.jpg'))),array('label'=>'EmtptyFolder','children'=>array())));
```

Please show me a way to create the whole directory structure at server side into the above array format.
Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Are you the same person that I've helped with the exact same question elsewhere?

Comment: @salathe curious about your solution to it though, so why not add your answer, regardless of whether it's the same OP?

Comment: @Gordon, the main difference between yours and mine would be that a nested array is returned rather than outputting the syntax.  I'm disinclined to post an answer if it is the same person.

Comment: @salathe I can understand that, but I'd also be interested in it, so it wouldn't be for the OP only. If you don't want to post here, could it possibly go into the Wiki?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may adjust this code to your needs. This is not a copy & paste solution as I needed it for a different UseCase, but it should get you at least halfway to implementing your own solution from it. The key lies in adjusting the methods `RecursiveIteratorIterator` will call when traversing the directory tree.

```
<?php
/**
* Prints a Directory Structure as an Nested Array
*
* This iterator can be used to wrap a RecursiveDirectoryIterator to output
* files and directories in a parseable array notation. Because the iterator
* will print the array during iteration, the output has to be buffered in
* order to be captured into a variable.
*
* <code>
* $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryAsNestedArrayFormatter(
*     new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/path/to/a/directory'),
*     RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
* );
* ob_start();
* foreach($iterator as $output) echo $output;
* $output = ob_get_clean();
* </code>
*
*/
class RecursiveDirectoryAsNestedArrayFormatter extends RecursiveIteratorIterator
{
    /**
     * Prints one Tab Stop per current depth
     * @return void
     */
    protected function indent()
    {
        echo str_repeat("\t", $this->getDepth());
    }
    /**
     * Prints a new array declaration
     * return void
     */
    public function beginIteration()
    {
        echo 'array(', PHP_EOL;
    }
    /**
     * Prints a closing bracket and semicolon
     * @return void
     */
    public function endIteration()
    {
        echo ');', PHP_EOL;
    }
    /**
     * Prints an indented subarray with key being the current directory name
     * @return void
     */
    public function beginChildren()
    {
        $this->indent();
        printf(
            '"%s" => array(%s',
            basename(dirname($this->getInnerIterator()->key())),
            PHP_EOL
        );
    }
    /**
     * Prints a closing bracket and a comma
     * @return void
     */
    public function endChildren()
    {
        echo '),', PHP_EOL;
    }
    /**
     * Prints the indented current filename and a comma
     * @return void
     */
    public function current()
    {
        if ($this->getInnerIterator()->current()->isFile()) {
            printf(
                '%s"%s",%s',
                str_repeat("\t", $this->getDepth() +1),
                $this->getInnerIterator()->current()->getBasename(),
                PHP_EOL
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow this cd be the ultimate solution for my problem , even  Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu does not extend recursive iterator iterator class to build tree , from where did you got an idea to override these methods ?? since they are not even documented @ php.net

Comment: @jason read a few bits on SPL here and there and everywhere. Note that the above *prints* the array instead of actually building it in memory. You will have to adjust that for your needs or give @salathe an answer so he might consider supplying his version that returns an array.