# How can I save a directory tree to an array in PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload, tree, directory

I'm trying to take a directory with the structure:

```
top
    folder1
        file1
    folder2
        file1
        file2
```

And save it into an array like:

```
array
(
    'folder1' => array('file1'),
    'folder2' => array('file1', 'file2')
)
```

This way, I can easily resuse the tree throughout my site. I've been playing around with this code but it's still not doing what I want:

```
private function get_tree()
{
    $uploads  = __RELPATH__ . DS . 'public' . DS . 'uploads';
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($uploads), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    $output   = array();

    foreach($iterator as $file)
    {
        $relativePath = str_replace($uploads . DS, '', $file);

        if ($file->isDir())
        {
            if (!in_array($relativePath, $output))
                $output[$relativePath] = array();
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Want to show Directory Tree of server  (PHP)  at client side using FLEX ??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191266/want-to-show-directory-tree-of-server-php-at-client-side-using-flex). Accepted solutions prints out directory tree as array. Just remove the part that would evaluate it back to a real array.

Comment: What do you want if there are folders within `folder1` or `folder2`?

Answer (score 4):

Im horrible with recursive functions. But i managed to come up with this..not sure it's what you're looking for

```
function tree($path, $top) {
    $ignore = array('cgi-bin', '.', '..' ); 
    $handle = opendir($path);   

    while( ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) {

        if( !in_array( $file, $ignore ) ){              
            if( is_dir("$path/$file") ) {
                $top[$file] = @ tree("$path/$file", $top[$file]);
            } else {
                $top[] = $file;
            }
        }

    }

    closedir( $handle );
    return $top;
}
```

Assuming your directory tree is

[image]

it outputs

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [aa] => Array
                (
                    [0] => aa.txt
                )

        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [0] => bb.txt
        )

    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => cc.txt
        )

)
```

But, take a break and go watch the eclipse that happens every 300 and something years. You dont want to say 'no' when your kids, grandkids, great-grandkids ask you 'did you know you were alive when the winter solstice eclipse occurred?? did you see it?????"

:)

Comment: update 6.5yrs later - id id see the eclipse, but don't even remember it.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you didn't address the case in which `$relativePath` is not a directory.  You did not describe your output, but i suppose it consists entirely of empty arrays without the desired files ever being inside.  Is this correct?

You need to handle the end-case where a file is reached instead of a directory.  Take a stab yourself, I can try to post for you later if you are still struggling.

Also, I'm afraid this won't deal with greater depths.  Although I am not sure if you need that based on your example.

--EDIT--

This won't build a full tree, as i explained the comment below, but depending on what you're looking for that might be ok.  A full tree would take some more significant changes.  However, what I post below should at least put the files into the folders.

```
private function get_tree()
{
    $uploads  = __RELPATH__ . DS . 'public' . DS . 'uploads';
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($uploads), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    $output   = array();

    foreach($iterator as $file)
    {
        $relativePath = str_replace($uploads . DS, '', $file);

        if ($file->isDir())
        {
            if (!in_array($relativePath, $output))
            {
                $output[$relativePath] = array();
                $lastDir = $relativePath;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
             $p = path_info($file);
             $d = $p['dirname']; $f = $p['basename'];
             $output[$d][] = basename($f); 
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, my output is something like: `array('folder1' => '', 'folder1/file1' => '')`. Not what I want. What do you mean by greater depths? It won't go deeper than two folders? I need it to do that... I'll keep playing around with it and see what I come up with.

Comment: it will go deeper than two folders in the sense that you can have an index like `['dir1/dir2/dir3']`, but not in the sense of `array(['dir1'] => array(['dir2'] => array(['dir3'] => 'file1')))`

Comment: this probably doesn't take you all the way there, but ive got to call it a night.  good luck!